# InvokeCommand arguments with ReactiveUI 7

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm switching to the latest version of ReactiveUI (7.0) and I'm running into some incompatibilities and would like to know the suggested way to handle this:

ReactiveUI 6.x

```
Texts.Events().MouseUp
     .InvokeCommand(ViewModel, x => x.DoSomething);
```

This now throws an exception:

> Command requires parameters of type System.Reactive.Unit, but received parameter of type System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.

I fixed this by using the following code, but is this the right way?

```
Texts.Events().MouseUp
     .Select(x => Unit.Default)
     .InvokeCommand(ViewModel, x => x.DoSomething);
```

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing the problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: The argument that the command was expection was Unit, meaning a command without an input argument which in the case of ReactiveUI is 
a ReactiveCommand<TReturnValue,Unit>. Thats why in the example above you have to 'convert'  the MouseButtonEventArgs from the event to a Unit.

For this I created a helper extension method ToSignal:

`public static IObservable<Unit> ToSignal<TDontCare>(this IObservable<TDontCare> source)
        => source.Select(_ => Unit.Default);`

Comment: That was obvious... thanks. Oh, also, you should post an answer to your own question and accept it, rather than commenting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument that the command was expection was Unit, meaning a command without an input argument which in the case of ReactiveUI is a ReactiveCommand. Thats why in the example above you have to 'convert' the MouseButtonEventArgs from the event to a Unit. For this I created a helper extension method ToSignal:

```
public static IObservable<Unit> ToSignal<TDontCare>(this IObservable<TDontCare> source) 
    => source.Select(_ => Unit.Default);

\\ The subscription will be then
Texts.Events().MouseUp
     .ToSignal()
     .InvokeCommand(ViewModel, x => x.DoSomething);
```